# How to include an escaped version of a file in a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, escaping

I have a static file that I want to include in a JSP.  The other file is to be treated as static text, not as a JSP.  This other file has special characters like "<%" in it.  Because of this I get errors when I try to include it.

How can I include this file with the characters escaped or with it being understood that it should be static?

`<%@ include file="/FileWithSpecialCharacters.html" %>`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that with an include.

But you could do it by reading and caching the file contents somewhere and then used `<%= ...%>` to insert it.  There are lots of possible variations on this theme.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html):

```
<c:import url="/FileWithSpecialCharacters.html" context="/other" var="doc"/>
```

You can use the `var` attribute to communicate between a `<c:import>` tag
and another tag that needs input.

```
<c:out value="${doc}"/>
```

`<c:out>`, by default, it makes sure that any characters with special meaning to HTML or XML are escaped using the entity references.

Answer (score 0):

How about read it in first as a resource, url encode it and write it out to another file - then include that. So I guess you'll have to do do a check first if equivalent, 'encoded' file already exists. Why the special characters in the first place?